# SNMP Custom Script Execution in Win 2008R2

Tags: windows-server-2008, scripting, snmp, conf

I'm trying to execute a custom Script that is readable from SNMP service.

Let's try to explain my purpose.

- I have a Win2008R2 server
- I have a PowerShell Script that "echo" something and return an Integer (error code ...)
- I'm trying to get my Script executed when a snmpwalk is launch toward my Server

Assuing I have my own OIDs, how can I do that ?
Is this even possible ?

Under Unix/Linux environement, I just have to add a line in snmpd.conf.

Answer (score 0):

Extending the Windows SNMP service for custom items can be done, but it isn't done through a script and modifying one text file. You need to compile a DLL that contains the routines that need to be run, and hook into the SNMP service to register the OIDs you want to handle.

While I have extended the Linux SNMP agent, I've never done it on Windows due to the difficulty.